# Automatically start perfmon on boot

Tags: windows-7, perfmon

Some of the work I do is heavily disk bound so I often have perfmon running for object **PhysicalDisk**, instance **C:** with counters **% Disk Read Time** & **% Disk Write Time**.

This is easy enough to set up but is there any way to start this configuration automatically on reboot?

There doesn't seem to be any way to save my counter set in perfmon once it has been set up.

Comment: You can use [logman](http://ss64.com/nt/logman.html)

Comment: [Performance Monitoring with Logman](http://www.travisgan.com/2012/09/performance-monitoring-with-logman.html)

Comment: [Two Minute Drill: LOGMAN.EXE](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2008/05/13/two-minute-drill-logman-exe/): "One of the key reasons to use LOGMAN.EXE is that we can specify which counters we want to capture in a standard configuration file"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the MMC.  Run mmc from Start-Run, then go to File – Add or Remove Snap-ins.  Add Performance to the selected snap-ins:

[image: MMC - Performance image]

Add whatever counters you want, then simply save it.

[image: MMC - Save image]

Close the MMC and you should be able to open the saved .msc file by simply double-clicking on it.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could help.